# How to center images horizontally with text?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am working on a site but the centering of my images horizontally in the footer isn't going very well.

When you make the screen smaller then 620px or something like that, then I want to center the text. But also the images.. With the images I mean the 5 icons in the third table and the picture in the fourth table.

If you try to decrease the width of the screen you will see that the images are not perfect aside the text.

So my question is.. How can I center the images horizontally with the text together when the text is aligned in the center?

Here is my footer: https://jsfiddle.net/ThomasPereira/L7dz7d4b/

I think that my mistake is here under -->

```
@media screen and (max-width: 623px) {
    #footer #group {
        padding-left:0px;
        max-width:100%;
    }
    #footer {
        height:1150px;
    }
    #footer #group #button {
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't good, you have many elements with the same id, and... `<img>` inside of `<a>` you need to read a little more about html rules, and organize the code a bit

Comment: how can I otherwise make a img a clickable link?

Comment: Why don't you try <table> It will be exactly side by side???

Comment: tried table.. not working for me. Maybe because I made a mistake??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L7dz7d4b/2/ try this if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED***
I just edited your fiddle a bit and managed to achieve what you wanted
https://jsfiddle.net/L7dz7d4b/2/

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 623px) {
        #footer #group {
            padding-left:0px;
            max-width:100%;
        }
        #footer {
            height:1150px;
        }
        #footer #group #button {
            text-align:center;
        }
        #footer #group a #icon {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 5px;
            float:none;
    }
 .opmaak{
        display:flex;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100px;
    }
    }
```

Comment: what should be the best then?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make images `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`

Smth. like:

```
.opmaak a img {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:-10px; /* value to nicely show img along text, */
}
```

P.S. You should have only unique ids. Use class instead of id if you have two elements with the same id.

Comment: thnx for the P.S. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Heres a simple guide](https://jsfiddle.net/79wr97ts/)

try to use `classes` rather than `ids` for things you need to use more than once. Using `inline-block` is very helpful, but keep in mind, things can get pretty messy if your css isn't good. For example, 2 `inline-block` elements will not align correctly if one has text, and the other doesn't.

Just some things to keep in mind.